# I can't get MySQL to launch via XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have tried everything from reinstalling to changing the config.

So I hope there is someone who can help me.

**Here is my error log**

```
2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2015-02-20 12:33:19 21e4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665284 and 1665284 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665294 in the ib_logfiles!

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from 
the .ibd files...

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2015-02-20 12:33:19 8952 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1665294
```

This is what it says in the control panel when I try to start MySQL:

> 13:28:38 [mysql] Attempting to start MySQL app...
>
> 13:28:38 [mysql] Status change detected: running
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] Status change detected: stopped
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method.
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 13:28:46 [mysql] entire log window on the forums

Comment: According to that log it is started, perhaps add the actual _reason_ you think it has not started?

Comment: oh yeah sorry my bad. it has started but cant seem to find the port

Comment: 13:28:38  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL app...
13:28:38  [mysql]  Status change detected: running
13:28:46  [mysql]  Status change detected: stopped
13:28:46  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:28:46  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:28:46  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Comment: Are you running Skype? Skype is known to interfere because of the port usage. In skype, change the portnumber.

Comment: yeah i know skype interferes. and i dont have skype running